# print ascii symbol with hex code value in python

Tags: python

What's proper way to print ascii symbol with hex code? say hex symbol └, need to be print out,the hex value is 0xC0.

ascii table reference is [here](https://www.matematica.pt/en/useful/complete-ascii-table.php)!

below code not work:

```
x = 0xC0
print(ord(x))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `chr`?

Comment: Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're talking about, cause 0xC0 is outside the ASCII range and that symbol `└` is Unicode U+2514 while Unicode U+C0 is `À`.

Comment: Oh, I added the reference link for ascii table, it says hex C0 for that symbol. is that table wrong?

Comment: It calls itself an ASCII table but it's not. ASCII doesn't go higher than 0x7f.  It isn't Unicode either.  Many character sets are supersets of ASCII, this appears to be one of those.

Comment: what do you want x to be equal exactly (the hex representation?) and  printed out?

Comment: That table also omits 0x20 == 32 == Space, which obviously IS ASCII.  You need to find a better reference.  ASCII is only 7 bits, because in the early days the 8th bit was used for parity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, that's technically not ASCII. ASCII only goes between 0x00 and 0x7F. From the looks of it, it looks like you're looking for [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

You can translate out of cp437 like so:

```
x = b'\xC0'
print(x.decode('cp437'))
```

Output:

```
└
```